# sql why is select statement unable to display the selected values

Tags: sql

I'm join 3 tables with the below statement

```
SELECT 
    c.FIRSTName, c.LASTName, r.feeOwe, r.paidorNotpaid, co.CITY, co.PERIOD, co.YEAR
FROM 
    CLIMBER c 
JOIN 
    REGISTER r ON C.CLIMBERID = R.CLIMBERID
JOIN 
    COMPETITION co ON CO.COMPETITIONID = R.COMPETITIONID;
```

[image]

I get the table I need however when I additional statements below, it does not show my desired results. Can anyone enlighten me.

```
SELECT 
    c.FIRSTName, c.LASTName, r.feeOwe, r.paidorNotpaid, co.CITY, co.PERIOD, co.YEAR
FROM 
    CLIMBER c 
JOIN 
    REGISTER r ON C.CLIMBERID = R.CLIMBERID
JOIN 
    COMPETITION co ON CO.COMPETITIONID = R.COMPETITIONID;
WHERE
    co.CITY = 'dubai'
    AND paidorNotpaid = null
    AND City = 'Dubai'
    AND Period = 'Summer'
    AND YEAR = 2015;
```

[image]

Comment: In order to evaluate NULL values in relational databases, you cant use `=`  or `!=` operators, instead of them you should use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` operators.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT c.FIRSTName, c.LASTName, r.feeOwe, r.paidorNotpaid, co.CITY, co.PERIOD,co.YEAR
FROM CLIMBER c 
JOIN REGISTER r 
  ON C.CLIMBERID = R.CLIMBERID
JOIN COMPETITION co 
  ON CO.COMPETITIONID = R.COMPETITIONID
WHERE co.CITY = 'dubai'
  AND paidorNotpaid IS NULL
  AND City = 'Dubai'             -- probably you use the same condtion twice
  AND Period = 'Summer'
  AND YEAR = 2015;
```

The `paidorNotpaid = null` => `NULL` that's why you don't get any record.

Do not use comparison operator with `NULL`. To check if column value contains `NULL` use `IS NULL` operator

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/400479)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

if your database is NOT case sensitive, try this:

```
SELECT c.FIRSTName, c.LASTName, r.feeOwe, r.paidorNotpaid, co.CITY, co.PERIOD,co.YEAR
FROM CLIMBER c 
JOIN REGISTER r 
  ON C.CLIMBERID = R.CLIMBERID
JOIN COMPETITION co 
  ON CO.COMPETITIONID = R.COMPETITIONID
WHERE co.CITY = 'dubai'
  AND r.paidorNotpaid IS NULL
  AND co.Period = 'Summer'
  AND co.YEAR = 2015;
```

Comment: Thanks guys, yes it was the 'NULL' that created the error! And now I learnt :)